# Is there a fix for my Google App Script below which ties into Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

I am getting the following error when I run my script add-on. The script is meant to update the URL links through an API service that runs from Thomson Reuters. I keep getting the same error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJnxt.png)

My script is below, is there a way to get rid of the error?

```
/**
* Runs when the add-on is installed.
* @param {object} e The event parameter for a simple onInstall trigger. To
*     determine which authorization mode (ScriptApp.AuthMode) the trigger is
*     running in, inspect e.authMode. (In practice, onInstall triggers always
*     run in AuthMode.FULL, but onOpen triggers may be AuthMode.LIMITED or
*     AuthMode.NONE.)
*/
/*function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen();
}


function updateImages() {
  // Gets the slides in the presentation.
  presentation = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  slides = presentation.getSlides();
  
  k = 0;
  
  // iterate through all the slides
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    // for each slide get all the images
    images = slides[i].getImages();
    // iterate through all images per slide
    for (j = 0; j < images.length; j++) {
      // if the SourceUrl property of an image is populated, refresh the image.
      // the SourceUrl property is only populated if the image was inserted using the 'By Url' method.
      if (sourceUrl = images[j].getSourceUrl()) {
        // only replace if the url is not googlesource content, i.e. therefore custom links.
        if (sourceUrl.indexOf('googleusercontent') == -1) {
          images[j].replace(sourceUrl);
          k++;
          Logger.log(sourceUrl);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  ui = SlidesApp.getUi()
  ui.alert('DONE!',k + ' image(s) were refreshed',ui.ButtonSet.OK);
}

*/

/**
* Trigger for opening a presentation.
* @param {object} e The onOpen event.
*/
/*function onOpen(e) {
  SlidesApp.getUi().createAddonMenu()
  .addItem('Refresh Images Inserted by URL', 'updateImages')
  .addToUi();
}*/
```

Comment: Can you post the test of the full error? At the moment it reads "The image at URL https:.... .... could not be retrieved. Please make sure that the ..." - is it that the image is in a supported format? Can you share a project that shows this error? See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sure, the error is The image at URL https://tmsnrt.rs/2O8VVqC could not be retrieved. Please make sure that the image is valid and publicly accessible.

Comment: I am trying to refresh the URL's through Thomson Reuters

Comment: Where is the URL coming from? Does the full URL have `https://` before the `tmsnrt...`? Can you share a sample presentation? How are you getting it via the API? If I try and put that link into a presentation with the URL (with https included) it works for me.

Comment: The URL is coming from Thomson Reuters. When I debugged the script I go this error : Error Script function not found: updateImages

Comment: Can you share the project and give more details? I want to try to reproduce the situation on my account to see what could be happening, but I don't have enough information and context.